# Hindi decoding error while sending message. Output is something like à¤µà¤? à¤¹à¤µà¦?à¦? à¤µà¤?à¤¹à¤µ à¤?à¤?à¤µà¦? à¤¹à¤µà¤¹à¦¬ à¤µà¤?à¤¹

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
    static String username = "######";
    static String password = "#####";
    static String senderid = "###";
    static String message = "वउह";

    static String mobileNo = "08447475458";
    static String mobileNos = "08447475458,08447475458";

    static String scheduledTime = "20110701 02:27:00";
    static HttpURLConnection connection = null;




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://msdgweb.mgov.gov.in/esms/sendsmsrequest");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
             connection = sendSingleSMS(username, password, senderid,
             mobileNo, message);

            System.out.println("Resp Code:" + connection.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Resp Message:"
                    + connection.getResponseMessage());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }               
    }
// Method for sending single SMS.
    public static HttpURLConnection sendSingleSMS(String username,
            String password, String senderId,
String mobileNo, String message) {
try {
    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String smsservicetype = "singlemsg"; // For single message.
            String query = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username)
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password)
                + "&smsservicetype=" + URLEncoder.encode(smsservicetype)
                + "&content=" + URLDecoder.decode(message,"utf-8") + "&mobileno="
                + URLEncoder.encode(mobileNo) + "&senderid="
                + URLEncoder.encode(senderId);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String
            .valueOf(query.length()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset = utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98; DigExt)");
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection
                    .getOutputStream());
        int queryLength = query.length();
        output.writeBytes(query);
        System.out.println(query);
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection
                    .getInputStream()); 
        for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read())
            System.out.print((char) c);
        input.close();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something bad just happened.");
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
```

I am using this code to send sms from gateway but this code is fine if the text is english but if I give some hindi text then its not able to read it and user gets some characters.

the output is something like

```
à¤µà¤? à¤¹à¤µà¦?à¦? à¤µà¤?à¤¹à¤µ à¤?à¤?à¤µà¦? à¤¹à¤µà¤¹à¦¬ à¤µà¤?à¤¹
```

Comment: Why exactly did you tag php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Applied this belore query string and its done

  ```
  System.out.println(message);
              String finalmessage = "";
              String sss = "";
              char ch = 0;

          for(int i = 0 ; i < message.length();i++){

               ch = message.charAt(i);
              int j = (int) ch;
          //  System.out.println("iiii::"+j);

              sss = "&#"+j+";";
              finalmessage = finalmessage+sss;
          }
          System.out.println("ddd"+finalmessage);

          message=finalmessage;
          System.out.println("unicoded message=="+message);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The `DataInputStream` is reading bytes, but then you have to properly convert those bytes to characters using the correct encoding. For that, you could construct a `String` using the constructor as follows:

```
String hindiCharSequence = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: if you can share me some link

Comment: If i use ` URLEncoder.encode(message,"utf-8")` then shows the output as %E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%B9

Comment: I am afraid I am out of ideas, then. If you find a solution to this, please share it here :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @ChthonicProject is the correct answer to accept, here a bit code. It uses a ByteArrayOutputStream to collect the bytes. A DataInputStream is more useful for reading binary ints and such. Better use just a buffering. And/or read a `byte[]` buffer of say 160 bytes.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection
                .getInputStream())) {
    for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read()) {
        baos.write(c);
    }
} // Closes input.
String msg = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.print(msg);
```

What you did, was considering every byte as a char. But with UTF-8 several bytes may make up a char, which is 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with the SMS encoding. By default it uses GSM 7-bit alphabet.
Check if you can specify which encoding will be used in SMS encoding.

Comment: OR UCS-2 for non-Latin script.